# How to get datetime with and without an offset?

Tags: java, date, parsing, time, timezone

Currently my method is able to parse and format date and time with an offset.

While I experienced with JUnit I discovered -for many people pretty obvious- mistake that I'm only able to parse it if it contains an offset.

I either get
`Unable to obtain OffsetDateTime from TemporalAccessor` or I can't parse time with an offset.

This is my code so far:

Working input:
 `"2020-01-12T10:30-06:00"`

Not working input:
`"2020-01-12T10:30"`

```
OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(date, buildIso8601Formatter());
Instant instant = offsetDateTime.toInstant();

return LocalDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneOffset.UTC);
```

It works fine for datetimes with an offset but not the other way around.

In the end I want to be able to parse a datetime with/without an offset in the same method.

Comment: Could you please add some example input?

Comment: @deHaar Updated it.

Comment: The example `String` is invalid because it is missing the `:ss` part for seconds. It just has hours and minutes. That means you have to provide a custom pattern in Order to parse it. Can you show the implementation (or the pattern used) of `buildIso8601Formatter()`, too?

Comment: Another possibility would be just to add the seconds, like `"2020-01-12T10:30:00-06:00"` and then simply do `OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(date)`.

Comment: @deHaar I'm able to parse it. I provided an example which doesn't work. The String can't be parsed without an offset. I tested it with and without seconds and it doesn't show a difference. I kinda understand why but I'm not able to find the correct path which leads me to a solution.

Comment: The `String` can be parsed, but not to an `OffsetDateTime`, use a `LocalDateTime` and add a specific offset afterwards, if necessary.

Comment: @deHaar What if the String already contains an ``OffsetDateTime`` like in my working example above? I was not able to parse it/get the offset out of it.

Comment: Just parse it to an `OffsetDateTime` and then invoke a certain method on it: `LocalDateTime ldt = offsetDateTime.toLocalDateTime();`

Comment: @deHaar If I do that I'm still not able to parse a String without an offset e.g. ``"yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm"``

Comment: If you managed to parse the datetime that missed the seconds to an `OffsetDateTime`, then you can use the same pattern for a `LocalDateTime`, just leave the offset symbols...

Comment: @deHaar If I parse the datetime to an ``OffsetDateTime`` it automatically uses ``ISO_OFFSET_TIME`` as formatter. I don't have to manage that, it is part of the ``DateTimeFormatter``.

Comment: Thanks for adding example input. Please also specify what output you want or expect from parsing `2020-01-12T10:30`. Asking because it’s not obvious to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Moment

> Working input: "2020-01-12T10:30-06:00"
>
> Not working input: "2020-01-12T10:30"

These inputs are two *very* different animals. The first represents a moment, the second does not. The first determines a specific point on the timeline, the second does not.

The second lacks the crucial context of a time zone or offset-from-UTC. So we do not know if the second input represents 10:30 in the 12th in Tokyo Japan, or 10:30 in Tunis Tunisia, or 10:30 in Toledo Ohio US – all very different moments, several hours apart.

### Faulty data source

If you have a source of inputs that arbitrarily omits the offset/zone info, then you don’t have a problem with your own Java programming, your data source has a problem.

Imagine a data source that provided a series of monetary amounts, some amounts indicating the currency of Canadian dollars, euros, or Japanese yen, while some amounts arbitrarily omitted any indication of currency. Obviously that would be considered faulty data that should be fixed at the source.

If you really want to work with this faulty data, simply look for the presence of a Plus or Minus sign. If found, parse as a `OffsetDateTime`. If omitted, parse as a `LocalDateTime`.

```
if( input.contains( "+" ) || input.contains( "-" ) ) {
    OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( input ) ;
} else {
    LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input ) ;
}
```

Alternatively, try to parse as one type. If [`DateTimeParseException`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeParseException.html) thrown, try the other type.

If you are *certain* the input missing its offset was intended for a particular zone or offset, apply that offset or zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone( z ) ;
```

If you want to lose the time zone while keeping the offset-from-UTC, to match your other `OffsetDateTime` objects, call `toOffsetDateTime`.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = zdt.toOffsetDateTime() ;
```

FYI, the difference between [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) and mere [offset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset)… An offset is just a number of hours-minutes-seconds ahead of (positive) or behind (negative) UTC, the  [prime meridian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_meridian). A time zone is much more. A time zone is a history of the past, present, and future changes to the offset used by the people of a particular region, as set (and often changed!) by their politicians.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can parse a `String` that has an offset to an `OffsetDateTime` directly, but you cannot to that with a `String` that doesn't have information about the offset or a time zone.

Do it somehow like shown here:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String working = "2020-01-12T10:30-06:00";
    String notWorking = "2020-01-12T10:30";

    // directly parse the String with an offset to an OffsetDateTime
    OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(working, 
            DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME);
    // parse the String without an offset to a LocalDateTime first
    LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(notWorking, 
            DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME);

    // print them just to see the results
    System.out.println(offsetDateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME));
    System.out.println(localDateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME));

    // then convert the LocalDateTime to an OffsetDateTime by adding a ZoneOffset to it
    OffsetDateTime fromLocalDateTime = localDateTime.atOffset(ZoneOffset.of("-06:00"));
    // and print that
    System.out.println(fromLocalDateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME));
}
```

The resulting output is

```
2020-01-12T10:30:00-06:00
2020-01-12T10:30:00
2020-01-12T10:30:00-06:00
```